# Rate limit/throttle for axios requests issue

Tags: promise, axios, bluebird, throttling, rate-limiting

In this class, the `get(item)` method returns a promise with the response data object that is obtained from the axios call

```
const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

class MyClass {
    constructor () {}

    get(item){

      console.log(`making request`);
      return wait(250).then(
        axios.get(`https://some_url.com/${item.id}`, {
              params: { api_key: "some_key" }
          }).then((response) => {
              console.log(`RESPONSE IS ${response}`);
              return new Promise( (resolve) => { return resolve(response); })
          })
        )

    }
}
module.exports = MyClass;
```

this is the outer function that calls `get(item)` the axios wrapper method repeatedly.
It is using bluebirdjs' `Promise.mapseries` (http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.mapseries.html)

```
var myClass = require('./myClass');
...
bluebird.mapSeries(someArray), function(arrayItem){
return new myClass().get(arrayItem)
 .then((response_object) => {
    //TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
  });
})
.then(function(something){
  // do nothing
  })
});
...
```

the code fails in the higher level function where it throws `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` as it executes before the axios with `250ms` delay is finished

This implementation is not working and I'm looking to fix it and rate limit/throttle correctly

Feedback appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change from this:

```
return wait(250).then(axios.get(...))
```

to this:

```
return wait(250).then(() => axios.get(...))
```

You have to pass a function reference to `.then()` so it can call it later.  You were calling it immediately and passing its return result to `.then()` which is not how `.then()` works.

Also, change this:

```
return new Promise( (resolve) => { return resolve(response); })
```

to

```
return response;
```

as they accomplish the same thing, but the second is a lot simpler.